# Error undefined offset: 64 in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I had this undefined offset problem

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 64
>
> Filename: jadwal/jadwal.php
>
> Line Number: 150

this is my view

```
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Sesi</th>
                            <th>Hari</th>
                            <th>Jam</th>
                            <th>Mata Pelajaran</th>
                            <th>Guru</th>                 
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                            $no = 1;
                            $v = array();
                            $n = count($dataMatpel);
                            if(!empty($dataMatpel))
                            {
                                foreach($dataMatpel as $record1)
                                {
                                $mtk = $record1->bobot*2;

                                $dataGuru = $this->jadwal_model->getDataGuru1($record1->id_matpel);
                                foreach($dataGuru as $r)
                                {
                                    $arrayguru[] = $r->nama_guru;
                                    $arraymatpel[] = $r->nama_matpel;
                                    //$z[$r->id_matpel] = $r->nama_guru;
                                }
                                $len = count($arrayguru);
                                $no++;
                                }
                            }

                            foreach ($arraymatpel as $keymatpel => $value) {
                                $idguru[] = $arrayguru[$keymatpel];
                                $idmatpel[] = $arraymatpel[$keymatpel];
                                //print_r($idguru);
                            }
                            $no1 = 0;
                            $len = count($arrayguru);

                            for($x = 0; $len >= $x; $x++){
                                //echo $s[$x] = $x;
                                $s[$x] = $idguru[$x];
                                $v[$x] = $idmatpel[$x];

                            }
                            if(!empty($dataPelajaran))
                            {
                                foreach($dataPelajaran as $record)
                                {

                        ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $no1; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $record->sesi; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $record->hari; ?></td>                      
                            <td><?php echo $record->jam_pelajaran; ?></td> 
                            <td><?php echo $v[$no1]; ?></td>                          
                            <td><?php echo $s[$no1]; ?></td>          
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                                $no1++;
                                }
                            } 
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
```

and this is my model

```
function getDataMatpel1()
{ 
    return $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM matpel 
                             where id_matpel <= 14 
                             ORDER BY rand()')->result();
}
function getDataGuru1($idmapel)
{ 
    return $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM guru, matpel 
                             where guru.id_matpel = matpel.id_matpel 
                             AND matpel.id_matpel = "'.$idmapel.'"')->result();
}
```

the error is on line 150 & 151 which means these code $s[$x] = $idguru[$x]; and $v[$x] = $idmatpel[$x];

what does it mean?

how can i fix this?

Comment: In your for loop change - `$len >= $x;` - to - `$len > $x;`

Comment: @KarloKokkak i've done that but it doesnt change the error

Answer (score 0):

You're counting the wrong array variable that you use in your for loop.

Change - `$len = count($arrayguru);` - to - `$len = count($idguru);`.

And you are using the wrong condition in your for loop.

Change - `$len >= $x` - to - `$x < $len`.

Updated code block.
**Change:**

```
   $len = count($arrayguru);

   for($x = 0; $len >= $x; $x++){
      //echo $s[$x] = $x;
      $s[$x] = $idguru[$x];
       $v[$x] = $idmatpel[$x];

   }
```

**To:**

```
$len = count($idguru);

for($x = 0; $x < $len; $x++){
   $s[$x] = $idguru[$x];
   $v[$x] = $idmatpel[$x];
}
```